# Como fazer uma estrutura de repetição no jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Tenho um relatório referente a um gabarito,consigo imprimir os campos que so tem um informação,mas no caso das respostas(que seriam varias por provas,normalmente uma por pergunta) eu não consigo

Segue o código a baixo

gabaritoR.jrxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-06-09T16:04:42 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="gabaritoR" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d03a1b71-aa8c-44a4-af4d-a498dcbbcde2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <parameter name="PROVA_ID" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT p.id as prova_id,
    c.nome as nome_do_curso ,
    i.nomefantasia as instituicao_nome ,
    s.titulo as titulo_da_sessao,
    q.enunciado as enunciado_da_questao , q.id as questao_id,
    aq.descricao as alternativa_da_questao ,
    aq.ordem as ordem_da_questao ,
    d.nome as nome_da_disciplina,
    q.resposta as resposta_questao

    FROM prova as p

    INNER JOIN curso as c ON p.curso_id = c.id
    INNER JOIN instituicao as i ON p.instituicao_id = i.id
    INNER JOIN prova_sessaoprova as psp ON p.id = psp.prova_id
    INNER JOIN sessao as s ON psp.sessoes_id = s.id
    INNER JOIN itemquestaoprova as iqp ON s.id = iqp.sessao_id
    INNER JOIN questao as q ON iqp.questao_id = q.id
    INNER JOIN alternativaquestao as aq ON q.id = aq.questao_id
    INNER JOIN disciplina as d ON p.disciplina_id = d.id

    WHERE p.id = $P{PROVA_ID}
    ORDER BY s.id,q.id,ordem_da_questao]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nome_do_curso" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="instituicao_nome" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="enunciado_da_questao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="questao_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="alternativa_da_questao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resposta_questao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nome_da_disciplina" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ordem_da_questao" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <group name="Resposta">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{questao_id}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="50">
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="130" y="20" width="100" height="30" uuid="93a97b64-8744-44cb-98c8-91cc4e2df0b0"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{questao_id}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="310" y="10" width="100" height="30" uuid="ecec3be5-91a1-4445-b9c2-b3821ebfd0ca"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{resposta_questao}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <title>
        <band height="216" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="60" y="100" width="50" height="30" uuid="d1cb6426-32dc-4024-920e-3673446dc901"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Curso :]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="100" width="100" height="30" uuid="af3428a7-4bc9-4387-966f-3cf4e9f9a927"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome_do_curso}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="330" y="100" width="80" height="30" uuid="cd43b398-ff60-4ab9-824b-402c40dc572b"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Instituição: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="410" y="100" width="100" height="30" uuid="99c559da-04c0-44e4-a3fe-4b836c3d29e3"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{instituicao_nome}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="60" y="160" width="110" height="30" uuid="2e36b729-c728-4602-af78-0e27e8985bb4"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Turma/Período:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="330" y="160" width="80" height="30" uuid="49ec7d81-054d-412a-b555-f90ac984bbd1"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Disciplina: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="170" y="160" width="100" height="30" uuid="3bef24e3-9089-46f0-9746-0cf0e7b6040e"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Text Field"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="410" y="160" width="134" height="30" uuid="23af8f2e-d3bf-4898-95f2-15621157ad38"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="DejaVu Sans Mono" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nome_da_disciplina}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="162" y="30" width="230" height="70" uuid="1086168a-a408-48b4-9656-215ffc3bfbb9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="26"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[GABARITO]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="10" y="90" width="540" height="111" uuid="80a18fd6-09dc-4b69-af9c-a68428d56a21"/>
            </rectangle>
        </band>
    </title>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="109" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

preview gabarito

[image: Gabarito preview]

Estrutura

[image: Estrutura]

Comment: Poderia colocar uma imagem do resultado que você quer?